# Datatable to eventhub and getting exceeding limit

Tags: c#, azure, datatable, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send a datatable/dataset to eventhub and getting below error message,  Is there a way to send huge volume of data over to eventhub?

```
public static void PushTableToEventHubs(DataTable dtTable)
    {
        EventHubClient eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(EventHubConnectionString, EventHubName);
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtTable);
        eventHubClient.Send(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)));
        eventHubClient.Close();
    }
```

The received message (delivery-id:0, size:18719987 bytes) exceeds the limit (262144 bytes) currently allowed on the link.

Answer (score 1):

The event hub is not designed for a large volume of big data packets. It is designed for large volumes of small (max 256kb) messages like for IoT scenario's. In your case you might be better of using other techniques or services depending on your scenario.

That said, you might be able to split up the big messages into smaller ones, but the main disadvantage is that it will make it more complex on the receiving side since you have to keep track of all the parts that make up the whole message before you can recreate one big data message.